# compilation nap - How can I make sbt to ring a bell when compilation is ready?

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I make sbt to ring a bell (or play a sound, or execute some system command, a shell command) when compilation is ready ?

Compilation usually takes 40 seconds or more, so I'd like to take a little nap while waiting, 100 compilations is already one hour sleep.

Comment: I don't know the exact voodoo words you have to type but you can make a custom task that depends on the compile task and executes whatever you like afterwards.

Comment: thanks, I read up on this... something like this : http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Custom-Settings.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might want to stay on the warm JVM and stay in the SBT console,

There is an SBT plugin for what you're looking for:
https://github.com/orrsella/sbt-sound

It comes with some nice configurable options:

```
sound.play(compile in Compile, Sounds.Basso) // play the 'Basso' sound whenever compile completes (successful or not)

sound.play(compile in Compile, Sounds.None, Sounds.Pop) // play the 'Pop' sound only when compile fails

sound.play(test in Test, Sounds.Purr, "/Users/me/Sounds/my-sound.wav") // play 'Purr' when test completes successfully
                                                                       // or the wav file 'my-sound' when it fails
```

Comment: Looks like this plugin hasn't been updated since 2018 and isn't working for me on sbt 1.5.4/jvm 17, I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/audio/AudioStream`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [growler plugin](https://github.com/softprops/sbt-growl-plugin) which calls growl/notify with test results. This will give you an idea of what to do. Otherwise, a custom task would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I use simple bash commands:

```
sbt compile && say "Finish"
```

If you want notification even when it fails, replace by

```
sbt compile; say "Finish"
```

Comment: The advantage of this is that you can nap a bit longer cause you get the sbt startup lag every time :p